# extracting strings with strstr and using unique variable names causes "initialization makes integer from pointer" warning

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

I made a program in C that takes a string and converts the separator to null characters so my string can be left in place while I have a series of pointers (defined by ss) that point to the beginning of each string segment. I can act on those pointers directly with printf() but when I assign them to a variable, I get an "warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast" and the arrow in the compiler points to the value after the equals sign.

I want to avoid strtok and strsep and friends because I heard strtok overwrites memory spaces and strsep I think is for windows only. Plus I want something that is within the standard C library.

Am I declaring them incorrectly or is using simple variable names not possible in my scenario?

Here is my entire code with relevant documentation included:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>


  int main(){
  char bufo[1024]; //We need to make space for string, blank it and store it
  memset(bufo,0,1023); //or execution will crash
  strcpy(bufo," This is\r\n a test\r\n String \r\n Thank you \r\n your computer \r\n bye");
  char *sp=bufo;//set movable pointer to start of string
  char* ss[10]; //setup an array of string pointers
  int spn=1;    //string pointer starts at 1...
  ss[0]=bufo;   //because the 1st entry is full string unless \r\n is found
  while((sp=strstr(sp,"\r\n"))){
      //as we find \r\n, replace it with 2 nulls and skip over it
      *sp++='\0';*sp++='\0';ss[spn++]=sp;
  }
  //Trying to use simple labels to reference string segments inside the huge
  //string produces "warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast"
  //from C compiler

  //So this doesn't work (I have to delete the following 6 lines if I want the program to work 100%
  char* piece1=ss[0],piece2=ss[1],piece3=ss[2],piece4=ss[3],piece5=ss[4];
  printf("piece 1: '%s'\n",piece1);
  printf("piece 2: '%s'\n",piece2);
  printf("piece 3: '%s'\n",piece3);
  printf("piece 4: '%s'\n",piece4);
  printf("piece 5: '%s'\n",piece5);

  //But this does work, but I don't want to use ss[x] all the time...
  printf("The results....\n");
  printf("piece 1: '%s'\n",ss[0]);
  printf("piece 2: '%s'\n",ss[1]);
  printf("piece 3: '%s'\n",ss[2]);
  printf("piece 4: '%s'\n",ss[3]);
  printf("piece 5: '%s'\n",ss[4]);
  }
```

Comment: "*I want to avoid strtok and strsep and friends because I heard strtok overwrites memory spaces*…" It's true that `strtok` overwrites the delimiters with NULs. But so does your function, so I'm not quite sure what the advantage is.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
char* piece1=ss[0],piece2=ss[1],piece3=ss[2],piece4=ss[3],piece5=ss[4];
```

You're declaring one variable of type `char *` and four variables of type `char`.  The `*` binds to the variable, not the type.  What you currently have can also be written like this:

```
char *piece1=ss[0],piece2=ss[1],piece3=ss[2],piece4=ss[3],piece5=ss[4];
```

Which should make it more clear what the problem is.  You instead want:

```
char *piece1=ss[0], *piece2=ss[1], *piece3=ss[2], *piece4=ss[3], *piece5=ss[4];
```